# How to construct a numpy array from a list whose each element contains row and column indices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list `l` whose each element is of a form `[row_index, column_index, value]`. Then I would like to construct a numpy array `array_` from this list. This means `array_[row_index, column_index] = value` for `[row_index, column_index, value]` in `l`. We can generate an empty array and use loop to sequentially fill in the values. However, I think it not efficient. Could you elaborate on how to do so more efficiently?

```
import numpy as np
l = [[0, 0, 0.0],
     [0, 1, 14.0],
     [0, 2, 7.0],
     [1, 1, 0.0],
     [1, 2, 7.0],
     [2, 2, 0.0],
     [1, 0, 14.0],
     [2, 0, 7.0],
     [2, 1, 7.0]]
 
l
```

Comment: Since you are starting with a list of lists, that loop might well be the most efficient.  An alternative is to make a (n,3) array from `l`, and then assign all elements with one call.  `res[col[:,0], col[:,1]] = col[:,2]`.  Though with a float value column, you'll need to take extra steps to make the index columns integer dtype.

Answer (score 0):

l=np.array(l)

Simple method using  numpy

Answer (score 0):

to recap, code :

```
import numpy as np
l = [[0, 0, 0.0],
     [0, 1, 14.0],
     [0, 2, 7.0],
     [1, 1, 0.0],
     [1, 2, 7.0],
     [2, 2, 0.0],
     [1, 0, 14.0],
     [2, 0, 7.0],
     [2, 1, 7.0]]
 
l=np.array(l)

print(l,'\n',type(l), '\n',l.size, '\n',l.shape)
```

output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1. 14.]
 [ 0.  2.  7.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  7.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.]
 [ 1.  0. 14.]
 [ 2.  0.  7.]
 [ 2.  1.  7.]] 
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
 27 
 (9, 3)
```